# UI Text Field postioning Swift

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uikit

I am a newbie to ios development and am fairly confused about how to position a UI Text field in swift. I am working with sprite kit and am creating a gaem that involves inputing a quadratic equation. I want to position my text fields along side my labels so it say y=_x^2+*x+*. When I run the following code, my text fields are in the top left corner! What should I do?

```swift
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.blueColor()
        //create y = label 
        let yLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Note-Worthy-Bold")
        yLabel.text = "Y = ";
        yLabel.fontColor = SKColor.redColor()
        yLabel.fontSize = 30;
        yLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-300, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+100);
        self.addChild(yLabel)


        //create text fielld for coefiecent of x^2 variable
        var xSqrCoefInput = UITextField(frame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 10))
        xSqrCoefInput.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        self.view?.addSubview(xSqrCoefInput)


        //create x^2 Label
        let xSqrLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Note-Worthy-Bold")
        xSqrLabel.text = "x^2+";
        xSqrLabel.fontColor = SKColor.redColor()
        xSqrLabel.fontSize = 30;
        xSqrLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-150, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+100);
        self.addChild(xSqrLabel)

        //create text fielld for coefiecent of x variable
        var xCoefInput = UITextField(frame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 10))
        self.view?.addSubview(xCoefInput)
        xCoefInput.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        //create x label
        let xLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Note-Worthy-Bold")
        xLabel.text = "x+";
        xLabel.fontColor = SKColor.redColor()
        xLabel.fontSize = 30;
        xLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-0, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+100);
        self.addChild(xLabel)

        //create text fielld for constant
        var constantInput = UITextField(frame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 10))
        self.view?.addSubview(constantInput)
        constantInput.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`CGRectMake` takes in 4 parameters.

```
CGRectMake(x position, y position, width, height)
```

The default starting position is the **top-left corner**. Your current textfield position is (10,10), so basically you just have to change the x and y positions for all the textfields.

```
var xSqrCoefInput = UITextField(frame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 10))
```

If you wish to place the textfield next to the labels, it would be best to get the position of the labels and set the position from there.